# Trouble moving files in PowerShell using forfiles to a folder whose name has more than one word

Tags: cmd, forfiles

I'm new to PowerShell, and am trying to move a few excel spreadsheets into a folder titled "old folder" using the forfiles command. PowerShell says that the files have been moved, but when I check the folder they're not there. They aren't in their original location either.

```
forfiles /P C:\Users\NewUser\Desktop /M *.xlsx /D +27/05/2019 /C 'cmd /c move @file C:\Users\NewUser\Desktop\"old folder"\'
```

I tried changing the folder name to a single word "oldfolder" and it worked just fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is not powershell... Might be that you're running it in a powershell window, but your code is for Windows batch script. Try opening a `cmd` prompt and entering the same code

Comment: Are you sure this is PowerShell? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/forfiles

Comment: @arco444 just tried it in the cmd, but it still gives the same effect. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @wheebytes - have you tried doing this with _powershell code_ instead of BAT/CMD code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a problem with the syntax of your /C parameter. As far as I can tell the argument should be enclosed in double-quotes. And because of the space in the file name that should also be enclosed in double-quotes. Quotes within quotes should be escaped with backslash.
I would suggest this:

```
forfiles /P C:\Users\NewUser\Desktop /M *.xlsx /D +27/05/2019 /C "cmd /c move @file \"C:\Users\NewUser\Desktop\old folder\""
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know about the backslash escape sequence. Would like to add that this worked in the cmd. To get it to work in PowerShell I had to enclose the double quotes in single quotes like so:

`... /C 'cmd /c move @file \"C:\Users\NewUser\Desktop\old folder\"'`

Answer (score 0):

As `forfiles` has it's idiosyncrasies even in cmd, I wouldn't drag that along to PowerShell.
IIUR that translates to:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\NewUser\Desktop\*.xlsx' -File |
    Where-Object LastWriteTime -ge [DateTime]::Today |
        Move-Item -Destination 'C:\Users\NewUser\Desktop\old folder\'
```

Not sure if you meant that to be `/D -27/05/2019` => `-lt` or `-le` instead of `-ge`